# GCC_VERSION gcc-6.2.0 is given error: enable_if is not a class template but same code is working with gcc-4.3.0

Tags: c++

Getting following error with GCC_VERSION gcc-6.2.0 but same code is working with gcc-4.3.0 :

> char_traits.h:27:8: error: enable_if
>   is not a class template

```
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type;};
```

> char_traits.h:27:25: error: redeclared with 1 template parameter

```
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

> char_traits.h:24:8: note: previous
>   declaration template struct enable_if used 2
>   template parameters  `struct enable_if {};`
>
> char_traits.h:32:22: error: expected nested-name-specifier before enable_if
>        `typedef typename enable_if<sizeof (T) == sizeof (char)>::type eif;`

```
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

template<typename T>
struct is_char
{
    typedef typename enable_if<sizeof (T) == sizeof (char)>::type eif;
};
```

could you please help to resolve these errors ?

Comment: You can replace your condition with the standard std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, char>::value>::type, if the condition fails the returned type must be a void type.:

Comment: gcc 4.3.0 predates C++11. gcc 6.2.0 dates from about 2016.  The 2011 C++ standard introduced `std::enable_if`.    You have code that declares a name `enable_if` and presumably has `using namespace std` at file scope in effect as well.   That will explain the errors.    Either rename your enable_if to something else that doesn't clash or remove the `using namespace std` from all your code.  Preferably both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are most likely because you have a `using namespace std;` [at file scope](https://godbolt.org/z/UPJk9V).

The template `enable_if` in the code is conflicting with the `std::enable_if` pulled in because of the `using` declaration.

This conflict  occurs only with GCC 6.2.0 because this version supports C++11 which was when `std::enable_if` was added to the language.

This conflict does not occur with GCC 4.3.0 because this version does not support C++11 and does not have the implementation of `std::enable_if`.

So get rid of the file scope and global `using` declarations and this will [compile with GCC 6.2.0](https://godbolt.org/z/Ul67t6) as well.